# Rselenium xpath not able to save response

Tags: r, xml, curl, rselenium

I'm trying to get the stocks from https://www.vinmonopolet.no/ 
for example this wine https://www.vinmonopolet.no/vmp/Land/Chile/Gato-Negro-Cabernet-Sauvignon-2017/p/295301

Using Rselenium

```
library('RSelenium')
    rD=rsDriver()
    remDr =rD[["client"]]
    remDr$navigate("https://www.vinmonopolet.no/vmp/Land/Chile/Gato-Negro-Cabernet-Sauvignon-2017/p/295301")
    webElement = remDr$findElement('xpath', '//*[@id="product_2953010"]/span[2]')
    webElement$clickElement()
```

It will render [Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUlMd.jpg)

But how to store it?
[Full XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wmq6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe be `rvest` is what you are looking for?

```
library(rvest, tidyverse)

url <- "https://www.vinmonopolet.no/vmp/Land/Chile/Gato-Negro-Cabernet-Sauvignon-2017/p/295301"

page <- read_html(url)
stock <- page %>%
  html_nodes(".product-stock-status div") %>% 
  html_text()

stock.df <- data.frame(url,stock)
```

To extract the number use

```
stock.df <- stock.df %>% 
  mutate(stock=as.numeric(gsub(".*?([0-9]+).*", "\\1", stock)))
```

Comment: Thanks! but that only reads the HTML side. It is only when you click on "Finn butikk med varen på lager" that you trigger this: ('xpath', '//*[@id="product_2953010"]/span[2]') and it will send a query to the server. You get the response as shown previously but how to read it?

Comment: @user3460688 hm, not sure i understand what you mean. the code which i put up provides you with a dataframe incuding a) the link to the wine, and b) the number of bottles in stock.

Comment: your code gives me stock available "Post/På dør: 36 på lager"  (36 bottles) where as the total amount (in the response XML is 9815 bottles)

Comment: your code is correct if i only want to know the stock available by post "Post/På dør: 36 på lager"  (36 bottles) where as If you want to know the entire stock in all the shops in Norway you need to do a "click" (webElement) and then you will get an XML with the stocks by shop.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work just sending the right plain request no need of R

```
https://www.vinmonopolet.no/vmp/store-pickup/1101/pointOfServices?locationQuery=0661&cartPage=false&entryNumber=0&CSRFToken=718228c1-1dc1-41cd-a35e-23197bed7b0c
```